# Why does a declared string take an integer

Tags: java, string, int

In this code I declare conversion as a String. But when I input an integer my program proceeds and it works. I didn't think it should work when i enter an integer (since conversion is declared as a string). Why does this work?

```
import java.util.*;

//  we want to input a number and then convert that number into an int 
//  Integer.parse(), and then continue
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean set = true;
        int sum = 0;
        while(set != false){
            int i = 0;
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            String conversion = input.nextLine();
            try{
               int x = Integer.parseInt(conversion);
               sum += x;
                if (x == 0){
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
                    System.out.println(sum);
                    break;
               }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                break;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `String var = "1";` work?

Comment: Yeah but in this case I haven't converted it yet. String var = "1" works because its a string. But in this case i'm entering integers and it accepts it.

Comment: What do you mean by "i'm entering integers"? Which line are you surprised about? `String conversion = input.nextLine()`? The `nextLine()` method returns a string... it's not like typing in a number is going to change the return type.

Comment: Until `Integer.parseInt`, you're only working with Strings.

Comment: Oh i see. I assumed that you had to physically type"1". But i guess it makes it a string automatically. That make sense then. Thanks!

Comment: So if i change it to  -- > int conversion = input.nextInt(); I get a compiler warning. Is it anyway to get it to run. I'm trying to practice catching exceptions.

Comment: Putting a string in double quotes is a convention of the Java programming language. It only applies to Java *source code*, not to text read from files or the console. When you're reading from a Scanner, it isn't interpreting what you type as source code.

Comment: Are you still doing `Integer.parseInt(conversion)`? That isn't valid if `conversion` isn't a `String`, since `parseInt` takes a `String` as its parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It works because you are converting a string to an int with Integer.parseInt().